# How easy is it to change a B22 light fitting to an E27 one?

Tags: electrical, lighting, uk

I was looking to fit some Philips Hue LED bulbs, but they only come with Edison screw fittings (E27) and every light fitting in our house is bayonet (B22). I initially looked into using adapters but I was concerned about the quality and couldn't find a reputable brand. Is this something that I can change myself? For the avoidance of doubt, I live in the UK and I am not a qualified electrician.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that Philips Hue now come with B22 (bayonet) fitting as well.

Comment: I was curious so I looked it up, and for the avoidance of doubt, in case anyone reading this question is wondering, replacing a light fitting is [non-notifiable under Part P of the building regulations](http://electrical.theiet.org/building-regulations/part-p/faqs.cfm) and therefore does *not* require a qualified person to either do the work nor to certify it as sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's usually pretty easy to change the fittings:

- make sure electricity is off (turn off the breaker that powers the light)
- double check the electricity is off
- loosen the screws that hold it up on the ceiling and keep the wires attached. Remember which wire is connected to the ground (bare/green or yellow green striped wire), live (red, orange or blue wire) and neutral (black wire) connections. If your house is newer then the colors may be different: green/yellow stripe for ground, brown/black or gray for live and blue for neutral
- connect the wires as indicated in the manual for the new fitting
- attach the new fitting to the ceiling
- put in new bulb
- turn electricity back on, if the breaker doesn't want to stay on you did something wrong and should inspect what you did wrong before trying to "fix" the breaker.
- toggle the switch and bask in your accomplishment.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy as ratchet freak described. The only problem is if your old lamp shade or similar will still fit. E27 is wider.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE A B22 TO E27 CONVERTER!!! You can put a bayonet bulb in either way and it still works because the two pins are underneath. The E27 only has ONE pin for live, BUT, put a converter in one of the two ways and the screw section may be LIVE - you might be able to touch the outer live area as you screw in the bulb.

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing what you're saying. Could you find a picture somewhere online or make a rough drawing of what you're talking about? [Edit]ing that into your answer would help it tremendously.